# Infinite product of $(2^{1/3})(4^{1/9})(8^{1/27})(16^{1/81}) \cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine the value of the infinite product $(2^{1/3})(4^{1/9})(8^{1/27})(16^{1/81}) \cdots$

I started by changing the bases all to $2.$

So now, this sum becomes $2^{1/3}\cdot 2^{2/9}\cdot 2^{3/27}\cdot 2^{4/81}\cdots$

We can add the exponents up, so that becomes $1/3+2/9+3/27+4/81\cdots.$

I noticed the top is an arithmetic series, and the bottom is a geometric series. How would I evaluate the exponents?

Comment: Hint: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \sum_{n=1}^{ \infty} n x^n= \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** The sum you are trying to calculate is

$$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{n}{3^n}.$$

We have

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x},\quad |x|<1$$

Now derive both sides and do something smart..

Answer (score 1):

$S=2^{1/3} \cdot 2^{2/9} \cdot 2^{3/27} \cdot 2^{4/81} \ldots $

$S^3=2^{1/1} \cdot 2^{2/3} \cdot 2^{3/9} \cdot 2^{4/27}$

$S^2=\dfrac{2^{1/1} \cdot \color{red}{2^{2/3}} \cdot \color{blue}{2^{3/9}} \cdot \color{green}{2^{4/27}} \ldots}{\color{red}{2^{1/3}} \cdot \color{blue}{2^{2/9}} \cdot \color{green}{2^{3/27}}}$

$=2^{1/1} \cdot2^{1/3} \cdot 2^{1/9} \cdot 2^{1/27} \ldots$

Is that better?

Edit: To those too hasty to judge me:

$S^2=2^{1/1+1/3+1/9+1/27 \ldots}=2^{3/2}$

$S=2^{3/4}$

[image]

Comment: The exponents are now a proper geometric series that can be summed up. I'll add that into my answer then

Answer (score 0):

Let $ n $ be a positive integer greater than $ 1 \cdot $

Denoting : $$ f_{n}\left(k\right)=\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}\frac{1}{3^{n}},\ \ \textrm{If }k\leq n\\ 0,\ \ \textrm{If }k>n\end{aligned}\right. $$

Then, using the summability of the family $ \left(f_{n}\left(k\right)\right)_{\left(n,k\right)\in\left(\mathbb{N}^{*}\right)^{2}} $ and Fubini's theorem, we get : $$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{n}{3^{n}}}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}{f_{n}\left(k\right)}}=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{f_{n}\left(k\right)}}=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}{\sum_{n=k}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{3^{n}}}}=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}{\left(\frac{\frac{1}{3^{k}}}{1-\frac{1}{3}}\right)}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2}}=\frac{3}{4} $$